# Python: plotting several arrays in a single plot using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I have several arrays (more than this, about 20 x arrays and 20 y arrays) but this is an example

```
xa1=[0,...3000]
ya1=[0,...3000]
xa2=[0,...3000]
ya2=[0,...3000]
xa3=[0,...3000]
ya3=[0,...3000]
```

I want to plot these arrays in a single plot using a for loop

I try first making an array of arrays

```
xarr = np.array([[xa1],[xa2],[xa3]])
yarr = np.array([[ya1],[ya2],[ya3]])

for i in range(3):
 plt.plot(xarr[i], yarr[i])
plt.show()
```

but my jupyter notebook crashes. I am new to coding, so could anyone help me improve this little code? or help me with an alternative? thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your syntax xarr[i] is not an array but a list with one item in it and THAT item is an array.  Matplotlib won't like that.

Try initializing xarr as a list instead, i.e. [xa1,xa2,xa3], and the same for yarr: you don't need them to be arrays, just a list OF arrays for the for-loop to iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

**xarr** and **yarr** are two concatenated arrays. You need to specify the column when you select them, so [i, 0]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xa1=range(0,150)
ya1=np.random.rand(150)
xa2=range(0,150)
ya2=np.random.rand(150)
xa3=range(0,150)
ya3=np.random.rand(150)

xarr = np.array([[xa1],[xa2],[xa3]])
yarr = np.array([[ya1],[ya2],[ya3]])

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(xarr[i,0], yarr[i,0])
plt.show()
```

[image]